# Sorted exsl:node-set. Return node by it position

Tags: xslt, xpath, position, exslt, node-set

I have a set of nodes

```
<menuList>
  <mode name="aasdf"/>
  <mode name="vfssdd"/>
  <mode name="aswer"/>
  <mode name="ddffe"/>
  <mode name="ffrthjhj"/>
  <mode name="dfdf"/>
  <mode name="vbdg"/>
  <mode name="wewer"/>
  <mode name="mkiiu"/>
  <mode name="yhtyh"/>
  and so on...
</menuList>
```

I have it sorted now this way

```
 <xsl:variable name="rtf">
    <xsl:for-each select="//menuList/mode">
       <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="@name"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
```

Now I need to get an arbitrary element in the sorted array to the number of its position. I'm using the code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($rtf)[position() = 3]"/>
```

and I get a response error. How should I be doing it?

Comment: See my answer, which explains the issues in your and @Tomalak's solutions and provides a correct solution.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are at least two errors in the provided code:**

1. **`<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>`**

When more than one adjacent text node exist, they are combined into one. The result is that the RTF has just one (long) single text node, and there isn't a 3rd node.

`2`.**`<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($rtf)[position() = 3]"/>`**

This asks for the third node contained in `exsl:node-set($rtf)`, however `exsl:node-set($rtf)` is the document node of the temporary tree produced by the `exsl:node-set()` extension function -- this is only one node. Therefore the above XPath expression doesn't select anything at all.

**One correct solution is the following**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 >

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="//menuList/mode">
           <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="@name"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)/*[position()=3]/@name"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have attached a your code and everything turned out. Without you I would not have coped. I have this sort was necessary for my last question: "XSL: List divided into columns.". Now (with your help) the code works completely correctly (first is sorting, then the partition of the columns). Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You use `<xsl:value-of>` in your variable. This does not copy the node, but its *string value* (the node's `@name` attribute value). This means you produce a variable containing a concatenated string, but nothing with a structure.

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="rtf">
  <xsl:for-each select="//menuList/mode">
    <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

*Now* your variable contains a result tree fragment consisting of `<mode>` nodes in your preferred order, which means that this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($rtf)/*[3]/@name" />
<!-- don't forget you have element nodes now! ^^^^^^ -->
```

would work. Also note that `…/*[position() = 3]` and `…/*[3]` are the same thing.

Comment: @Tomalak
I did everything as you said. But in response to received nothing.

Comment: @Tomalak, Actually, your solution isn't correct and isn't producing anything.

You are comitting mistake 2. described in my answer.

Comment: Also you claim that the `<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>` in the OP's code doesn't produce anything. In fact, this produces a text node, consisting of the string value of the `@name` attribute.

Comment: @Dimitre, you are right, that was sloppiness on my part. I've corrected my answer in this regard.

Comment: @Tomalak Glad I spotted it. Now it's OK.